# Circle fade out over time on Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am attempting to fade circles out with a setInterval on fillOpacity. However a console log shows the opacity changing but the appearance of the circle does not seem to change. Is there a different set function required to do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/faaxeskg/5/

```
        setInterval(function() {
         marker.fillOpacity -= .01;
        console.log(marker.fillOpacity);
    }, 200);
```

code snippet:

```js
var map = null;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922)
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  // Add 500 markers to the map at random locations
  var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(-31.203405, 125.244141);
  var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
  var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();


  setInterval(function() {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(
      southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),
      southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random());

    var populationOptions = {
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.65,
      map: map,
      center: position,
      radius: 40000
    };

    var marker = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);

    setInterval(function() {
      marker.fillOpacity -= .01;
      console.log(marker.fillOpacity);
    }, 200);

    setTimeout(function() {
      marker.setMap(null);
      delete marker;
    }, 30000);

  }, 2000);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="float:left;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to associate the "opacity change" to the marker, you can do that with function closure (a createCircleMarker function).
2. Don't use undocumented properties.  Use the documented methods.

   marker.set("fillOpacity, marker.get("fillOpacity")-0.01);

working code snippet:

```js
var map = null;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922)
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  // Add 500 markers to the map at random locations
  var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(-31.203405, 125.244141);
  var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
  var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();


  setInterval(function() {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(
      southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),
      southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random());

    var populationOptions = {
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.65,
      map: map,
      center: position,
      radius: 40000
    };
    createCircleMarker(populationOptions);

  }, 2000);
}

function createCircleMarker(populationOptions) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);

    setInterval(function() {
      marker.set("fillOpacity",marker.get("fillOpacity")-0.05);
      console.log(marker.fillOpacity);
    }, 200);

    setTimeout(function() {
      marker.setMap(null);
      delete marker;
    }, 30000);
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="float:left;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
```